# Ajax Control to filter data in a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, ajax, drop-down-menu, filter

I'm making a web application using ASP and AJAX, and I have a DropDownList with some data. I've used a ListSearchExtender to filter data, and it searchs for the first data with the word contained.

But what I want is not to go to the first occurence of the data but to really filter the data, I mean, if I have this data in the list:

- abcd
- aaaa
- bbbb

and if I type "b", then the new list only must contains "abcd" and "bbbb", instead of contains everything and being selected "abcd", which is the first element which matchs with "b".

Thanks a lot.

PD: when I was typing the Tags before posting the question, I've seen that that's exactly what I'm looking for. When you type a word, it returns a list of words which contains the word typed. SO, it's not necessary to have a DropDownList, I can have a textbox instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like an [autocomplete](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/autocompletex) ? If you use jQuery try their autocomplete plugin. It doesn't get any easier than that.